# Database updated and email is sent but Mozilla Firefox browser alert error instead of success message

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, pdo, phpmailer

I am having a problem in Mozilla Firefox whereby the AJAX part is alerting the error message instead of the success message when I approved the appointment for the lecturer role. This does not happen in Chrome as well as Edge. When I tried to check the Network for response, nothing came out for Mozilla Firefox and the alert automatically close. Nonetheless, the email can be sent to the receiver and the database is updated regardless of the web browsers. I already tried to check the response via var_dump in PHP file as well as JSON.stringify() in the AJAX part to check the data passed back but failed. I have three different files related to each other for approving the appointment.

**i) ajax-approve-detail-appointment.php (This file is to call the modal box and put all the values in there to be passed to ajax-approve-appointment.php)**

```
<?php
    require ("global-include.php");

    if (isset($_POST['appointment_id']))
    {
        try 
        { 
            $fetch_query = "SELECT * FROM appointment
                            LEFT JOIN users AS student ON appointment.student_id = student.username
                            LEFT JOIN course_field AS field ON appointment.field = field.field_id
                            WHERE appointment.lecturer_id =  :lecturer AND appointment_id = :appointment_id";  
            $stmt = $db->prepare($fetch_query);
            $stmt->bindParam(':lecturer', $_SESSION['username']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':appointment_id', $_POST['appointment_id']);  
            $stmt->execute();

            while($data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
            {
                $appointment_id = $data['appointment_id'];
                $appointment_type = $data ['appointment_type'];
                $appointment_date = $data['appointment_date'];
                $appointment_time = $data['appointment_time'];
                $name = $data['name'];
                $email = $data['email'];
                $venue = $data['venue'];
                $remarks = $data['remarks'];
                $field_name = $data['field_name'];
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>

<input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $appointment_id; ?>" name='appointment_id' id='appointment_id' />
<input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $appointment_type; ?>" name='appointment_type' id='appointment_type' />
<input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $appointment_date; ?>" name='appointment_date' id='appointment_date' />
<input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $appointment_time; ?>" name='appointment_time' id='appointment_time' />
<input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $name; ?>" name='name' id='name' />
<input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $venue; ?>" name='venue' id='venue' />
<input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $email; ?>" name='student_email' id='student_email' />
<input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $remarks; ?>" name='remarks' id='remarks' />
<input type='hidden' value="<?php echo $field_name; ?>" name='field_name' id='field_name' />

<?php
// Retrieve the columns from the database to get lecturer name
    $sql = "SELECT username, name FROM users 
            WHERE user_id = :user_id";        

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    if ($stmt->execute(array('user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id'])))
    {
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
        {
           //fetch the rows
            $username = $row['username'];
            $name = $row['name'];

            echo "
              <input type='hidden' name='lecturer_name' id='lecturer_name' value='". $row['name'] ."' /> 
              <input type='hidden' name='lecturer_username' id='lecturer_username' value=". $row['username'] ." /> 
            ";
        }
    }
?>

<p>Are you sure you want to approve the appointment with this student?</p>
```

**ii) ajax-approve-appointment.php (This file is having the PHPMailer and the query to update the database)**

```
<?php
    require ("global-include.php");
    require ('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoLoad.php');
    require ('PHPMailer/smtp-credentials.php');


    if (isset($_POST['appointment_id']))
    { 
        try 
        {
          //fetch data
          //vardump($_POST['appointment_id']);
          //$appointment_id = $_POST['appointment_id'];
          $appointment_type = $_POST ['appointment_type'];
          $appointment_date = $_POST['appointment_date'];
          $appointment_time = $_POST['appointment_time'];
          $name = $_POST['name'];
          $venue = $_POST['venue'];
          $remarks = $_POST['remarks'];
          $field_name = $_POST['field_name'];
          $lecturer_name = $_POST['lecturer_name'];
          $student_email= $_POST['student_email'];

          $approve_appointment_query = "UPDATE appointment SET appointment_status='Approved' WHERE appointment_id= :appointment_id";
          $approve_statement= $db->prepare($approve_appointment_query);
          $approve_statement->bindParam(':appointment_id', $_POST['appointment_id']);
          $approve_statement->execute();

          //die($approve_statement);

          //PHPMailer set up      
          $approve_output="<strong>Greetings from STULEC,</strong> <br/>
          <p>Dear " . $name . ",  your appointment with the lecturer, " . $lecturer_name . ", has been approved. </p>
          The appointment details are such as below: <br/>
            <ul>
              <li>Appointment Type: ". $appointment_type ."</li>
              <li>Appoinment Date: ". $appointment_date ."</li>
              <li>Appointment Time: ". $appointment_time ."</li>
              <li>Venue: ". $venue ." </li>
              <li>Course Field: ". $field_name ." </li>
              <li>Remarks: ". $remarks . "</li>
            </ul>
          </p>
          <p>Please attend the appointment on time. If you wish to change the time of the the appointment, please login into STULEC and reschedule as fast as possible. Thank you.</p>";

          $mail = new PHPMailer;
          $mail->isSMTP();                                // Set mailer to use SMTP
          $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';             // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
          $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                   // Enable SMTP authentication
          $mail->Username = EMAIL;              // SMTP username
          $mail->Password = PASS;               // SMTP password
          $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                    // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
          $mail->Port = 587;                        // TCP port to connect to

          $mail->setFrom('stulecappointmentsystem@gmail.com', 'STULEC');  //From sender
          $mail->addAddress( $student_email , $name);  // Add a recipient
          $mail->isHTML(true);                    // Set email format to HTML

          $mail->Subject = 'STULEC | Approval of Appointment from Lecturer';
          $mail->Body    =  $approve_output;
          $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
          $mail->ContentType = 'text/html';  


          if (($approve_statement->execute()) && $mail->send())
          {
              echo 'The appointment is approved and an email has been sent to the student.';
          } 
          else 
          {
              echo 'Error: The appointment cannot be approved and an email has been sent to the student.';
          }

          $data = $approve_statement->fetchAll();
          echo json_encode($data); 

        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
          echo $e->getMessage();
        }  
    } 
    else
    {
        echo 'Nothing is approved';
    }
?>
```

**iii) lecturer-view-pending-appointment.php (This file has the AJAX and JQuery part)**

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    //fetch details that want to be approved
    $(document).on('click','.approve_data', function()
    {
      var appointment_id = $(this).attr('id');
      //var appointment_id = $("#appointment_id").val();
      $.ajax({
        async: true,
        url: "ajax-approve-detail-appointment.php",
        type:"post",
        data:{appointment_id:appointment_id},
        success:function(data)
        {
          $("#approve_details").html(data);
          $("#approveModal").modal('show');
        }
      });
    })

    //approve appointment
    $(document).on('click','#btnApprove', function()
    {
      var appointment_id = $("#appointment_id").val();
      var appointment_type = $("#appointment_type").val();
      var appointment_date = $("#appointment_date").val();
      var appointment_time = $("#appointment_time").val();
      var name = $("#name").val();
      var venue = $("#venue").val();
      var remarks = $("#remarks").val();
      var field_name = $("#field_name").val();
      var lecturer_name = $("#lecturer_name").val();
      var student_email = $("#student_email").val();

      $.ajax({
        url: "ajax-approve-appointment.php",
        type:"post",
        data:{appointment_id:appointment_id, appointment_type:appointment_type, appointment_date:appointment_date, appointment_time:appointment_time, name:name, venue:venue, remarks:remarks, field_name:field_name, student_email:student_email, lecturer_name: lecturer_name},
        success:function(data)
        {
          alert('The appointment with this student is successfully approved.');
          $("#approveModal").modal('show');
          location.reload();
        },
        error: function(data) 
        {
          //JSON.stringify(data);
          alert('Error: The appointment with this student cannot be approved!');
          $("#approveModal").modal('show');
          location.reload();
        }
      });
    })

  });
  </script>
```

From ajax-appprove-detail-appointment.php, the network response is like below:
[image]

From ajax-approve-appointment.php, the network response in none:
[image]

Here is the network for params for ajax-approve-appointment.php:
[image]

Hope that you can point out to me what is the problem because I am not really an expert in AJAX and JQuery. Thank you.

Comment: I can see you put lots of work into formatting this, but there's really too much code here. The act of cutting this back to a minimal example will probably mean that you find the problem anyway, but if you don't, it will create a better, more focused question that's easier to help with. If you use something like postman to generate your requests, it allows you to ignore any client-side JS issues - it looks like you have a server-side issue, so I'd check your error logs.

Comment: @Synchro: hello Sir. as per your advice, I removed some of the codes that I feel not so related to the question. do you think it is still long? btw, regarding the error logs which I take a look in xampp apache folder, I can't really find anything related to the response. Its very strange.

Comment: Set some break points in your code or output some debug notices to be sure where your code is getting to. Work on the PHP part in isolation, don’t try to get the JS working until you know the PHP works.